# How to access subcategory without having url-key of the parent category in the url?

Tags: url, redirect

How to access subcategory without having url-key of the parent category in the url?
for example

```
aboutus---parent category
  about vc---sub category
  about gurkha---sub category
```

Now I have to redirect sub category to page named about-vc and about-gurkha without going through parent category.link should open like this

```
magento.com/index.php/about-vc 
magento.com/index.php/about-gurkha
```

not like

```
magento.com/index.php/about-us/about-vc
```

Thank You

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You want the sub category URL without the parent category in the path?

Comment: I have rephrased the question to "How to access subcategory without having url-key of the parent category in the url?" hope that matches your intended question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could also solve this using CMS pages. You can always include products in a CMS page too using static blocks or widgets. Have you tried creating 2 CMS pages with the following URL keys?

1. about-vc
2. about-gurkha

If that doesn't help, you can create redirects using the following steps:

1. Navigate to Catalog > Catalog URL Rewrites in admin area
2. Click "Add URL Rewrite"
3. Choose "Custom" from the dropdown
4. Fill out the form with the following details:

**Store:** The store view this URL rewrite will apply to. You must create one redirect for each store view
**ID path:** aboutus
**Request path:** about-vc.html
**Target path:** catalog/category/view/id/
**Redirect:** No

This will tell Magento to load a category page when the user requests "about-vc.html". You can change this value to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I didn't need .html extension too in the page..

Comment: Jus look at my website menu whats wrong in menu url please tell me..Thanks in advance
www.gurkhablades.com

Answer (score 0):

To Remove .html from url, do the following

There is an easy way to improve the SEO of your Magento store by removing the .html extension from the url

Example:

We have a category called Shoes

http://example.com/default/shoes.html
And we want to have an URL like this:

http://example.com/default/shoes
Now go to your Admin Panel. System -> Configuration. Then go to Catalog and expand the Search Engine Optimization tab.

Remove the “.html” text from both the input fields. Product URL Suffix and Category URL Suffix.

Comment: did it worked ? if so you might want to mark as answer....this will help others..